# java - can't use log4j in project explorer of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, log4j

I updated eclipse version to 4.9.0
my project used log4j library in maven.
but maven build raise error that block maven dependencies in project explorer of eclipse.

please teach me how to do this problem.
thanks.

[capture screen] https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MjfC.jpg

I used code below in pom.xml

```
<org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: [ERROR] InnovationCampaignDataExcelBuilder.java:[10,16] [deprecation] Font in jxl.write has been deprecated
[ERROR] ClickCountLogController.java:[9,23] error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] ClickCountLogController.java:[21,22] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Logger
  location: class ClickCountLogController
FacebookServiceImpl.java:[56,89] [unchecked] unchecked cast

Comment: [ERROR]   required: HashMap<String,Document>
  found:    Object
FacebookServiceImpl.java:[57,115] [unchecked] unchecked cast
[ERROR]   required: HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>>
  found:    Object
MongoDBConnectionManager.java:[199,2] [rawtypes] found raw type: List


thank for reply

Answer (score 0):

I moved the Eclipse version to Neon 4.6.3.
so I resolved that shown block to log4j.
but raise error below:

please how to resolve this error
thank you for reply.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.joins::war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.mybatis:mybatis:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 3.2.2 @ line 249, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @  ---
[INFO] Deleting joongangClickCountDashboard\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @  ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @  ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 188 source files to D:\sean-workspace-neon\ClickCountDashboard\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] ClickCountDashboard/src/main/java/com/joins/innovation/campaign/excel/InnovationCampaignDataExcelBuilder.java:[10,17] jxl.write.Font in jxl.write has been deprecated
[WARNING] ClickCountDashboard/src/main/java/com/joins//facebook/service/impl/FacebookServiceImpl.java:[56,104] unchecked cast
  required: java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,org.bson.Document>
  found:    java.lang.Object
[WARNING] ClickCountDashboard/src/main/java/com/joins//facebook/service/impl/FacebookServiceImpl.java:[57,130] unchecked cast
  required: java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>>
  found:    java.lang.Object
[WARNING] ClickCountDashboard/src/main/java/com/joins//common/db/MongoDBConnectionManager.java:[199,17] found raw type: java.util.List
  missing type arguments for generic class java.util.List<E>
[WARNING] ClickCountDashboard/src/main/java/com/joins//common/db/MongoDBConnectionManager.java:[201,126] unchecked method invocation: method aggregate in interface com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection is applied to given types
  required: java.util.List<? extends org.bson.conversions.Bson>
```

I has settings in maven below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```